# View counter in ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, counter

How would I do this?  Seems like webservices php/mysql setup.  I’m not the best with these things.  Is there an easier way?  I appreciate suggestions.  I just want to count how many times an area in the app is viewed and display the count within the app.

Comment: For that one user, or for everyone who uses your app?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Parse](https://www.parse.com/). I've never used it for anything in production, but if I were making an app that required a server component I definitely would. It's free up to a million API requests per month and pretty much eliminates 99% of the work that would go into setting up your own server/database/API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Analytics](https://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html) or [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) to count page views and so on.

Comment: @DavidStucke view count for single user or all users of your app? For single user, you can add some counter in `viewDidAppear`. For all users, you need to post the count to your serve and get for all users.